# DirectX 9 advanced tutorials C++ 

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi, directx-9

I don't need tutorials talking about fvf or how to draw a triangle. I need some free tutorials that are about advanced things like meshes shadering.

Comment: Google has [lots of resources](http://www.google.com/search?q=directx+shaders+tutorial) if you can ask for a specific thing. You can only get so far with online material, sometimes you just need to buy or borrow a book. Books are superior resources.

Comment: i agree with you sometimes books are the only solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't too many good tutorials I've seen on mesh shaders, but it's not too hard to figure out yourself if you understand both shaders and meshes.

If I understand what you mean by "mesh shadering" properly (guessing shaders applied to meshes, material shaders I call them), then you simply have to use the D3DXEffect stuff and apply the shader before drawing the mesh.

IF you're trying to understand shaders, there are plenty of books around that cover almost every aspect, for all different languages and systems. It's oddly hard to find a simple tutorial, but for anything more complex, the GPU Gems series comes to mind.